# Hibernate configuration files not found by Axis2

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, apache-axis, hibernate3

I am writing a web service to be deployed on Tomcat using Axis2. I am using Hibernate3 to persist data between the web service and a MySQL database.

When running the application through by IDE, the method I am exposing through Axis2 works as intended, however when I deploy the .aar to Tomcat, I receive a SOAP Error claiming that hibernate.cfg.xml cannot be found.

However, inside the .aar, I clearly see that all the configuration file and all the mapping files are included.

I have determined a workaround: If I place the resulting files from the Netbeans build/class folder into the axis2/WEB-INF/class folder, then the application works as expected.

My question, then, is is there a better way to deploy my application so that Axis2 will pick up the configuration and mapping files through the deployed .aar without my manually having to copy the contents of the build/class folder into the axis2/WEB-INF/class folder?

Answer (score 0):

In the .aar archive there should be a /META-INF/services.xml file. Edit that file and set the ServiceTCCL parameter to composite for your service:

```
<parameter name="ServiceTCCL">composite</parameter>
```

Then put hibernate.cfg.xml in the same META-INF directory within the .aar archive. This will make the configuration file available for Hibernate to load from the classpath.

Comment: I seem to lose the container wide (jboss) jndi context. My InitialContext.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction")
returns null. How to I get the container level context back?